# Spark cast column to sql type stored in string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The simple request is I need help adding a column to a dataframe but, the column has to be empty, its type is from ...spark.sql.types and the type has to be defined from a string.

I can probably do this with ifs or case but I'm looking for something more elegant. Something that does not require writing a case for every type in org.apache.spark.sql.types

If I do this for example:

```
df = df.withColumn("col_name", lit(null).cast(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType))
```

It works as intended, but I have the type stored as a string,

```
var the_type = "StringType"
```

or 
    var the_type = "org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType"

and I can't get it to work by defining the type from the string.

For those interested here are some more details: I have a set containing tuples (col_name, col_type) both as strings and I need to add columns with the correct types for a future union between 2 dataframes.

I currently have this:

```
for (i <- set_of_col_type_tuples) yield {
    val tip = Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types."+i._2)
    df = df.withColumn(i._1, lit(null).cast(the_type))
    df }
```

if I use

```
val the_type = Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types."+i._2)
```

I get

```
error: overloaded method value cast with alternatives:   (to: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>   (to: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)org.apache.spark.sql.Column  cannot be applied to (Class[?0])
```

if I use

```
val the_type = Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types."+i._2).getName()
```

It's a string so I get:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: mismatched input '.' expecting {<EOF>, '('}(line 1, pos 3)
== SQL == org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
---^^^
```

EDIT: So, just to be clear, the set contains tuples like this ("col1","IntegerType"), ("col2","StringType") not ("col1","int"), ("col2","string"). A simple cast(i._2) does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Spark accepts a string in the `cast` function. The supported values are: `string`, `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `date`, `timestamp`. ([ref](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column))

Comment: @DanieldePaula That's the answer (I was quicker by few seconds ;) )

Comment: Thanks but what you recommend  is the less elegant method I mentioned. It requires matching "StringType" to "string", "IntegerType" to "int"  and so on. Like I said I can do this but I want something that does not require this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use overloaded method `cast`, which has a String as an argument:

```
val stringType : String = ...
column.cast(stringType)
```

> def cast(to: String): Column
>
> Casts the column to a different data type, using the canonical string
>   representation of the type.

You can also scan for all Data Types:

```
val types = classOf[DataTypes]
    .getDeclaredFields()
    .filter(f => java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()))
    .map(f => f.get(new DataTypes()).asInstanceOf[DataType])
```

Now types is Array[DataType]. You can translate it to Map:

```
val typeMap = types.map(t => (t.getClass.getSimpleName.replace("$", ""), t)).toMap
```

and use in code:

```
column.cast(typeMap(yourType))
```

Comment: Please check my edit, this is not the solution I'm looking for. This or I don't fully understand what you suggest and an example would help. Thanks

Comment: Well, not exactly what I was hoping for but it works :). The 
typeMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType] 
you create is done automatically and the solution you recommended (unlike a series of ifs) will hold if new types are added to the package in the future so it is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @UrVal you can still iterate on your DataFrame and use this map inside for, like in your example `.cast(typeMap(i._2))`

Comment: Yes, I checked it before accepting the answer and it worked, thanks :)