# Converting string name to sql datatype in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been referring to the below article

[Spark cast column to sql type stored in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981469/spark-cast-column-to-sql-type-stored-in-string/45981564#45981564)

I am looking for the equivalent code in pyspark.

The problem is that the answer in the above post uses `classof[DataTypes]` but `DataTypes` class is not available in pyspark.

What I am trying to do is create the Schema dynamically. so, I have a List as below:

```
>>> sourceToHiveTypeList
['TimestampType', 'TimestampType', 'StringType', 'StringType', 'IntegerType', 'DoubleType']
```

and I have defined a UDF

```
def TableASchema(columnName, columnType): 
   return StructType([
       StructField(columnName[0], getattr(pyspark.sql.types,columnType[0]), nullable = True),
       StructField(columnName[1], getattr(pyspark.sql.types,columnType[1]), nullable = True),
       StructField(columnName[2], getattr(pyspark.sql.types,columnType[2]), nullable = True),
       StructField(columnName[3], getattr(pyspark.sql.types,columnType[3]), nullable = True),
       StructField(columnName[4], getattr(pyspark.sql.types,columnType[4]), nullable = True),
       StructField(columnName[5], getattr(pyspark.sql.types,columnType[5]), nullable = True)
      ])
```

When I call the above UDF, I get error:

```
>>> schema = TableASchema(headerColumns, sourceToHiveTypeList)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in TableASchema
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TimestampType()'
```

Comment: What do you mean DataTypes isn't available? It's a module, not a class, if that's what you mean...  http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I believe that OP refereed to `classOf]

Comment: Check answer here -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777648/inferring-spark-datatype-from-string-literals/57199266#57199266 you can create instance of DataType using plain scala reflection.
Also the Catalyst parser provides creating DataType instance when datatype is stored as sql data type string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a solution, which works only for atomic types (same as the one in the linked question):

```
import pyspark.sql.types

def type_for_name(s):
    return getattr(pyspark.sql.types, s)()

type_for_name("StringType")
# StringType
```

Complex types could parsed with `eval`, but due to security implications, I would be very careful:

```
def type_for_name_(s):
    types = {
        t: getattr(pyspark.sql.types, t) 
        for t  in dir(pyspark.sql.types) if t.endswith("Type")}
    t = eval(s, types, {})
    return t if isinstance(t, pyspark.sql.types.DataType) else t()

type_for_name_("DecimalType(10, 2)")
# DecimalType(10,2)
```

In general I would recommend using short strings (i.e. `string`, `double`, `struct<x:integer,y:integer>` which can be used directly:

```
col("foo").cast("integer")
```

and if you need more complex representation use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def toDataType(dataType: String): DataType = {
    val module =
      runtimeMirror.staticModule("org.apache.spark.sql.types." + dataType)
    runtimeMirror.reflectModule(module).instance.asInstanceOf[DataType]
}
```

Comment: error: not found: value runtimeMirror . How can I resolve this while using above solution?